# How to add links in all cells of a table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have currently a table made with ng-repeat in Angular. The cells value is set by some variable in scope.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" myDirective>
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.field}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I would like to do is to have this in the end :

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" myDirective>
    <td><a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.field}}</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I created a directive in order to do that but I don't go anywhere with it.
I tried to get every child of the tr element, then surround the html of the (td) childs by a  tag but it seems that the binding removes the tag and replace it with vanilla item title and field.

Here is my code so far, which is setting the a tag with a status website on the first td tag (title) but can't make it work.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        var cellules = element.children(); // get td elements
        angular.element(cellules[0]).html($compile('<a href="http://website">' + angular.element(cellules[0]).html() + '</a>')(scope)); // surround title with a link
      }
    };
  });
```

Thank you !

Comment: This probably doesn't answer the question fully, but you should be implementing your directive with "-" notation not camelcase... `<tr ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive>`

Comment: How would we know what `cellules[0]` is? Provide [mcve]. Also just saying it doesn't work isn't much of a problem description

Comment: @sourdoughdetzel yes you are right and it is actually like that in my code but I made a mistake changing the names for the example :)

Comment: @charlietfl cellules is the array of children of the tr tag so it is (should be) the array of td elements.

Comment: I am finding it hard to determine the problem. Have you tried using ng-href for you purpose?

Comment: @SpartakLalaj yes, and unfortunately ng-href (or simple href) doesn't work with td or tr tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive,

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            link:'=link',
            title:'=title'
        },
        template:'<a href={{link}}>{{title}}</a>'
    };
});
```

HTML,

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <td my-directive link='item.link' title='item.title'></td>
    <td my-directive link='item.link' title='item.field'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was my initial idea however I want to create the same link (`<a href ={{item.link}}>...</a>`) for all the cells and not the first one. With this technique I should create a directive for every field in the table which is not very convenient.

Comment: Thank you. What I was looking for was a "shorter" way to do it by just adding the link and the directive in the tr tag (as I have 5-6 td tags in each row and possibly more in the future) but at least this is a working solution. Thank you again !